# How do you know the partition letter of the SSD that just fried?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

My OS is Windows 11 and I just encountered a multiple SSD failure due to PSU malfunction some part of the board on SSD are damage and BIOS can't pick it up anymore.

How can I know the damaged SSD partition letter if which one are which, it fried at the same time and I forgot which SSD partition letter, The drives are not the same brand though.

My important files are on one of these and I want to send it to data recovery service but I don't want to pay it twice.

Comment: Data recovery on SSDs is not in any way guaranteed.  Having good backups is a much better strategy.  Also, for long term happiness, get a good quality computer.

Comment: Did you manually assign drive letters or let windows handle that? Maybe add what partitions you had on what drive. do you remember what drive contained c:?

Comment: short answer is, that you probably can't, without more info.

Comment: How many partitions did you have on the drive? Presumably you'd recall which drive you put the important stuff on? Most people just leave a single partition, and on Windows that would usually be labeled "C:". Windows also defaults to saving everything on C: unless you've modified it on purpose to behave differently.